# ExpressRoute - Private Peering - Storage Account Firewall

Tags: azure, storage, firewall

Have a storage account that I need to enable the firewall on. I've already put in place private endpoints and create the necessary Private DNS domains to allow privatelink.blob.core.windows.net to work correctly (on-premises requests resolve to the correct RFC1918 address). The issue I have is with locking down the storage account.

I am unable to specify the on-prem IP ranges since they are RFC1918 addresses. The only way I can see to allow access is via VNet/Subnet or via an explicit public IP address. I've read a bit about using the NAT address of the ExpressRoute but that seems to only pertain to Microsoft or public peering. There shouldn't be any NAT happening.

For reference. The ER is terminating into a hub and the VNet where the storage endpoint is located is peered with this hub.

Thanks,
Nathan

Answer (score 0):

Network Security Group (NSG) support for private endpoints is in public preview.  (Preview features do not have the same SLA's as generally available features and are not recommended for production.) Depending on your region, you may be able to use this feature: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/public-preview-of-private-link-network-security-group-support/

An NSG could be associated with each subnet that contains a private endpoint to the storage account.  An inbound rule could then be added to the NSG that allows traffic from the on-premises IP's to the private endpoint IP's.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the right direction. I don't want to block traffic, I want to whitelist on-premises addresses. Similar to how storage accounts currently allow you to whitelist public IP addresses.

Comment: @Nathan - My apologies - I thought that "enable the firewall" and "locking down the storage account" meant that the objective was to block traffic.  What leads you the believe that traffic isn't being allowed?  Do you have a virtual network gateway in the hub with gateway transit enabled?

Comment: it seems that when I do enable the firewall on the storage accounts, the local VNets are able to access since I do add them but non-VNet source traffic (on-prem) gets blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's too late for the answer, but you need a DNS conditional forward for the onprem workloads to work with private endpoints. If you don't use it, you will always resolve the query to the public endpoint instead of the private one.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-endpoint-dns